# How to access dockerized rails server using "localhost"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I don't play often with Docker so I'm really confused here.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG RUBY_VERSION
FROM ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-slim-buster

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION

# common dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    curl \
    less \
    git \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -fr /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
  && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
  && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# add postgresql to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# add nodejs to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# add yarn to sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# application dependencies
# we use an external aptfile for that
COPY Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
  libpq-dev \
  postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
  nodejs \
  yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
  $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
  truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# configure bundler

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3

# upgrade rubygems and install required bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
  gem install bundler:${BUNDLER_VERSION}

# create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .dockerdev
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.4'
        NODE_MAJOR: '11'
        PG_MAJOR: '13'
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.7.2'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.22.5'
    image: example-dev:1.0.0
    tmpfs: 
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
      - .dockerdev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/usr/local/bundle/_bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/app/log/.psql_history
      - EDITOR=vi
      - MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=${WEB_CONCURRENCY:-1}
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy

  runner:
    <<: *backend
    command: /bin/bash
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3002:3002'

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  sidekiq:
    <<: *backend
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C configs/sidekiq.yml

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
      - ./.dockerdev/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/root/log/.psql_history
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
      interval: 5s

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    ports:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: redis-cli ping
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30
  
  webpacker:
    <<: *app
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}
      - RAILS_ENV={RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

Everything works just fine, I can run my `runner`, install gems, play with db, run `rails`, etc.

Until I try to reach `http://localhost:3000` which only shows:

> This site can’t be reached 
> localhost refused to connect.

Here is the step I do to run rails server:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm rails
Creating okamii-saas_rails_run ... done
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.7.2-p137), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And here is the result of `docker-compose ps`:

```
               Name                             Command                  State                Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
okamii-saas_postgres_1               docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32789->5432/tcp
okamii-saas_rails_run_6fff67202995   bundle exec rails server - ...   Up
okamii-saas_redis_1                  docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32788->6379/tcp
```

I have the feeling that the fact that nothing shows in the `Ports` column for `okamii-saas_rails_run_6fff67202995` is a sign something is wrong but I don't know why it is empty and what I am supposed to do here. (cf. EDIT 1)

As a note, I know the title say `how to using localhost` but I really can't access it at all AFAIK :)

===

EDIT 1:

That's not entirely true. I figured that by adding `EXPOSE 3000` in my `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose ps` will show something in the column `Ports` for my container but that did not change things a bit.

Here is an updated view of `docker-composer ps` when using `EXPOSE 3000`:

```
               Name                             Command                  State                Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
okamii-paas_postgres_1               docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32771->5432/tcp
okamii-paas_rails_run_d812907346b4   bundle exec rails server - ...   Up             3000/tcp
okamii-paas_redis_1                  docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32770->6379/tcp
```

EDIT 2:

From what I can read from [the doc about `EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), it is only acting as a documentation. It does not do anything else which explains why using it does not change anything.

EDIT 3:

I just tried running `docker-compose up -d rails` instead of `docker-compose run rails` and this message started spawning:

```
$ dc up -d rails
Creating network "okamii-paas_default" with the default driver
Creating okamii-paas_postgres_1 ... done
Creating okamii-paas_redis_1    ... done
Creating okamii-paas_rails_1    ...
Creating okamii-paas_rails_1    ... error

ERROR: for okamii-paas_rails_1  Cannot start service rails: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint okamii-paas_rails_1 (5d07dfedfc5c979133ce61a237327edb149a0a6793a85f61f6ad8218a60a510b): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for rails  Cannot start service rails: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint okamii-paas_rails_1 (5d07dfedfc5c979133ce61a237327edb149a0a6793a85f61f6ad8218a60a510b): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I don't understand where the conflict comes from.

After @dbugger's suggestion, I tweaked the ports publication from `"3000:3000"` to `"3000"`. And now, stuff shows in the `Ports` column but of course, the mapping is wrong.

```
         Name                       Command                  State                Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
okamii-paas_postgres_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32784->5432/tcp
okamii-paas_rails_1      bundle exec rails server - ...   Up             0.0.0.0:32786->3000/tcp
okamii-paas_redis_1      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32785->6379/tcp
```

Comment: At the end of your dockerfile, try adding the command `EXPOSE 3000`

Comment: @dbugger I tried it once and except for changing the result of `docker-compose ps`, I still can't access `localhost:3000`. I have updated my post if you want to see what it looks like.

Comment: Any reason you have runner running on port 3000 too?

Comment: Next thing I 'd tweak would be changing the ports config for rails from 3000:3000 to 3000

Comment: Regarding `runner` and its ports, I can't remember. But since I am not running it, it is not conflicting. Though, just for the sake of testing, I removed them I reran everything with no luck.I tried tweaking the ports like you suggested and it does not change anything.

Comment: @dbugger I made an **EDIT 3** which might brings more infos on what is going on.